# Delete orphaned msi files

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

I have a computer with 50GB of hard drive and it is almost full (I won't get an upgrade for C because is the company computer) I just check and the `C:\Windows\Installer` directory  is eating more of that space. I tried using msizap.exe to delete the unneeded files but I keep getting this error:

```
MsiZap V 5.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved

MsiZapInfo: Performing operations for user S-1-5-21-2700949330-2022528980-61785034-4992
Removing orphaned cached files.
   Error opening 66FC8F6438BA7A83992B5AEB05E74E27\InstallProperties subkey of Products key for S-1-5-18 user. Error: 2.
   Error opening 9AC087DE786021C34B9333962F4249F1\InstallProperties subkey of Products key for S-1-5-18 user. Error: 2.
FAILED to clear all data.
```

What can I do now?

Comment: contact your company's IT departement and have them do it

Comment: Would love to, but as I know them, it will take three months before the solve the problem

Comment: Did you run `MSIZAP` as an administrator when you executed it?

Comment: yes, all developers have administrator privileges in their computers

Comment: Just had the same issue / figured out that the key in question is under `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\` 
**SID** `\Products\` **GUID** `\InstallProperties`; where SID is the SID mentioned in the error (i.e. `S-1-5-18`), and GUID is the code from the error (e.g. `66FC8F6438BA7A83992B5AEB05E74E27`).  The issue is that the `InstallProperties` key doesn't exist (look at all the other entries).  The question is...dare I create a blank on and rerun msizap...

Comment: Update: I exported the key, deleted it, then reran `msizap g` (and then reimported the reg file).  The result was boringly pedestrian; the error was gone, but I got "no product/patch data was found`.  FYI: In my case the GUID was `99E80CA9B0328e74791254777B1F42AE`; which Google says is the D365 CRM Outlook add-in.

Answer (score 0):

## Background

The error is caused because an expected registry path does not exist.

e.g. for the error: `Error opening 66FC8F6438BA7A83992B5AEB05E74E27\InstallProperties subkey of Products key for S-1-5-18 user. Error: 2.`

The error doesn't tell you the full registry key path; but does give you the SID of the user under whom the missing entry exists; in this case `S-1-5-18` (i.e. the `Local System` account).

Looking in the registry under `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products` 
(substituting `S-1-5-18` with the relevant SID from the error, should it differ) we see a number of subkeys.

If we look under any of those subkeys we're likely to see another subkey, `InstallProperties`.  However, for the subkey with the GUID from the error message, the `InstallProperties` subkey does not exist.

```
$userSid = 'S-1-5-18'
$productId = '66FC8F6438BA7A83992B5AEB05E74E27'
$path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData'
$path = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $userSid
$path = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'Products'
$path = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath productId
Get-ChildItem -Path $path
# Note that InstallProperties is not listed
```

## Workaround

This involves editing the registry, and is not based on any documented information... **Use at your own risk** / take sensible precautions such as backing up anything you care about before running.

1. Open the registry editor (`WinKey` + `R` > `Regedit` > `OK`)
2. Navigate to the appropriate product key entry; e.g. `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\66FC8F6438BA7A83992B5AEB05E74E27` for the above.
3. Right click and select Export; so you're backing up this key's value.
4. Delete this key
5. (repeat the above for any other product keys with this error)
6. Re-run `msizap g`.  It should now run without error
7. Double click the *.reg file you created in step 3 to reload that key into the registry

Hopefully now all's worked successfully, and nothing's been broken by the workaround... Good luck!